# C++ Capturing Keyboard Specific Keys even when in a game

Tags: c++, keyboard, record, keystroke

I coded a program to update my k/d ratio while streaming and I wanted it to be easy to use, basically to be able to press "shift + 1" to increment my kills etc..
Now it works when I'm in google chrome and some other applications, but when I'm in a game, in this case Arma, when I press those keys it just doesn't do it, I have to alt+tab and than press the keys and it'll work.
Is there any way to make it so the key capture priority of the program is absolute, aka more important than Arma and will be capture even if I am in game?

Thanks

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_SHIFT, 0x31); // shift + 1
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 2, MOD_SHIFT, 0x32);// shift + 2
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 3, MOD_SHIFT, 0x33);// shift + 3
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 4, MOD_SHIFT, 0x30);// shift + 0
//shift + 1 = kill
//shift + 2 = death
//shift + 3 = reset
//shift + 0 = close;
int exit = 0;
int kill = 0;
int death = 0;

cout << "K: " << kill << endl;
cout << "D: " << death;

do
{
    int showKill = kill;
    int showDeath = death;
    do
    {
        MSG msg = {0};
        if (GetMessageA(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
            if(msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
            {
                if(msg.wParam == 1)
                    kill++;
                else if(msg.wParam == 2)
                    death++;
                else if(msg.wParam == 3)
                {
                    kill = 0;
                    death = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    exit++;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    while(kill == showKill && death == showDeath);

    system("CLS");//clear the console
    cout << "K: " << kill << endl;
    cout << "D: " << death;
}
while(exit == 0);


UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 1);
UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 2);
UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 3);
UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 4);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can think off from top of my head, there are two pretty straightforward ways how to resolve this assuming you're playing a game on Windows:

1. You write a hook and inject it into game.exe while running.
2. You use SetWindowsHookEx and capture keyboard low-level input events.

1st approach requires you to write a dll module, and with that you will be able to use most of your already written code, it should go something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI KeyThread(LPVOID)
{
    RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_SHIFT, 0x31); // shift + 1
    RegisterHotKey(NULL, 2, MOD_SHIFT, 0x32);// shift + 2
    RegisterHotKey(NULL, 3, MOD_SHIFT, 0x33);// shift + 3
    RegisterHotKey(NULL, 4, MOD_SHIFT, 0x30);// shift + 0
    //shift + 1 = kill
    //shift + 2 = death
    //shift + 3 = reset
    //shift + 0 = close;
    int exit = 0;
    int kill = 0;
    int death = 0;

    // There's no console here so cout won't work, you'll need to use MessageBox or make a file log somewhere
    cout << "K: " << kill << endl;
    cout << "D: " << death;

    do
    {
        int showKill = kill;
        int showDeath = death;
        do
        {
            MSG msg = {0};
            if (GetMessageA(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
                if(msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
                {
                    if(msg.wParam == 1)
                        kill++;
                    else if(msg.wParam == 2)
                        death++;
                    else if(msg.wParam == 3)
                    {
                        kill = 0;
                        death = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exit++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        while(kill == showKill && death == showDeath);

        system("CLS");//clear the console
        cout << "K: " << kill << endl;
        cout << "D: " << death;
    }while(exit == 0);


    UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 1);
    UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 2);
    UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 3);
    UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 4);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, KeyThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

After compiling dll you will need to inject it into your game process, I'd recommend [Winject](http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=357038) or [Extreme Injector](http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1022113). If you are a daredevil, you might go and write one yourself. I must note that if your game is multiplayer based and it uses anticheat, you might trigger some kind of offense if that anticheat is using whitelist system to scan for game modules instead of blacklist one.

2nd approach is to make normal executable file and [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) to monitor low-level keyboard events. I myself wrote this a long time ago, but since I couldn't find it, I will simply provide you with an [example of keylogger](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40755-good-keylogger/) that uses this approach, some slight modification and it should work perfectly, I've took a liberty and layout a basic stuff for you:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hKeyboardHook = NULL;
LRESULT WINAPI LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) || (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hooked_key = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        DWORD dwMsg = 1;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.scanCode << 16;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.flags << 24;
        char lpszKeyName[1024] = { 0 };
        lpszKeyName[0] = '[';
        int i = GetKeyNameText(dwMsg, (lpszKeyName + 1), 0xFF) + 1;
        int key = hooked_key.vkCode;
        lpszKeyName[i] = ']';

        if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z')
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) >= 0)
            {
                key += 0x20;
            }
                printf("%c \n", key);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("%s \n", lpszKeyName);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


int main()
{
    MSG message;
    HINSTANCE hins;
    hins = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)LowLevelKeyboardProc, hins, 0);

    // Message pump
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    return 0;
}
```

This second approach might be detected as malware by some antiviruses, but it will be able to print stuff into a console without any tweaking and is less complicated and straightforward to beginners.

I must mention the code examples weren't tested, so there might be some syntax error, but the logic itself should be correct.

Comment: So basically i need to turn this into a "real" keylogger ( simple way )
Makes sense, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows specific it should be easy to do with:

GetAsyncKeyState()

Read the documentation as this gives the state of the key and a particular bit is on/off when key is down/up.